# How to extract random screenshots from a swf file? In Linux

Tags: linux, flash

I need to automatically extract some random screenshots from Flash content (swf) in linux.

I will appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With a button within the swf ? From a script ? ???

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it. It has to be done through a script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to be easy, a guess at a possible implementation may be

- Run a virtual X server such as Xvfb (this is easy)
- Write a program which encapsulates the flash plugin, either by using a browser (for example Mozilla / xulrunner) or implementing the plugin interface directly and invoking the necessary logic. The Netscape plugin interface is documented.
- Have some way of waiting for the SWF to fully load, including all sub-components; I don't know how easy it is to tell, as there may not be callbacks for this.
- Wait until the flash has got to an interesting section (You may use some arbitrary criteria for this, either just time-based or content based)
- Stop the flash (possibly just by suspending the thread etc), and snapshot the window / screen you're using.

If you've got a Xvfb server you can use whatever resolution you want and use the whole screen.